# Is it OK to have Mac OS X application without an NSApplication instance?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In the Info.plist, I have one key "Application is background only" and its value is "Yes".
Most of the code is in C++.

The usual last line

```
return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
```

in main() is removed. Instead main starts some thread(s), blocks and waits on some condition to exit.

Comment: If your app wants to be included in run loop events and pretty much all the other standard Cocoa things, you need to have an NSApplication instance. If you just have a main method, you're responsible for whatever other code you'll need to be running.

Comment: Edit: The App uses a mix of C++ and Objective-C, and does use Cocoa classes. However it does not have a UI. If I try to get an NSRunningApplication instance with it's runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier method from a child process using this process's pid it returns nil. 

If I make changes to have 

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);

at the end of main, however, this method works and I can get NSRunningApplication instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can have a process (colloquially an application) without it, and it will work just fine with the Unix side of things, and behave just like any other headless process.

What you cannot have is an Application in the sense of a full-fledged Cocoa Application, because an instance of `NSApplication` (or a subclass) isn't just a part of your application, in a very real sense the main application object *is* the application. Things like reading the Info.plist, hooking into the Cocoa Application System, Applescript System, and so on is all done by `NSApplicationMain()`, making it a requirement of a capital-A Application.

It is possible you could set some of these things up yourself, but I don't know of any ways to do so, and even if I did, I *would not* recommend it. If you want your program to behave like an application and interact with the Cocoa side of things, `return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);` is the wait to end `main()` .

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is OK. NSApplication is declared in AppKit so it is used only in GUI apps. An app can use Foundation, which does not require NSApplication.

Comment: Meh.  I'd argue that it's not an application then.  It's just a command line utility...